# construction of Y gate from X,Z and H gates

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises, pauli-gates, universal-gates

As a part of textbook [exercise](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-states/single-qubit-gates), Y gate is to be constructed using H,Z and X-gates, just like we have $X = HZH$. is there some way/process/intuition to find such combinations or it is just like we need to use `hit and trial` method to find such combination?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you got a mistake there. The correct decomposition is
$$X = HZH.$$
The way you find the decomposition is by understanding that $HZH$ performs the change of basis. The right-most $H$ brings a vector from the $Z$ basis into the $X$ basis. Then $Z$ applies the $NOT$ operation in the $X$ basis. Finally, the left-most $H$ brings a vector into the $Z$ basis again.

Another way of looking at it is realizing that
$$X = HZH= H Z H^{\dagger}$$
is an [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) of $X$ where $H$ is a matrix of eigenvectors of $X$ and $Z$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $X$.

Following this logic, we can quickly decompose $Y$ by just knowing its eigenvectors and eigenvalues. So we get
$$Y = (SH) Z (SH)^{\dagger}.$$

Comment: made the edit for the typing mistake...thanks !!!